QEMU rebooting instead of halting
When i start QEMU it executes my code, but when it finishes it reboots and restarts instead of halting. I am using nasm and QEMU x86_64
Here is a gif of the problem

I also tried using -nographic but happens the same thing in the console.
It might be a problem of when i switch to protected mode, but i'm not sure.
To compile i use:
nasm -f bin .\src\boot\bootloader\bootloader.s -o .\build\build.bin -i .\src\boot\bootloader
and run it with:
qemu-system-x86_64 -hda .\build\build.bin
Here is my code:
bootloader.s
[org 0x7C00]
[bits 16]

_start:
    ; Initialize the stack
    mov bp, 0x9000
    mov sp, bp

switch:
    ; Disable interrupts
    cli

    ; Load GDT
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]

    ; Switch to 32-bit mode
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 0x1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp CODE:init

[bits 32]
init:
    ; Update the segment registers
    mov ax, DATA
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax

    ; Update the stack
    mov ebp, 0x90000
    mov esp, ebp

    ; Restore interrupts
    sti

    call begin

[bits 32]
begin:
    mov eax, string
    call print
    jmp $

%include "gdt.s"
%include "print.s"

string: db "Hello World!", 0x0

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55

gdt.s
[bits 16]

    ; GDT Descriptor Table
gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start

    ; GDT Table
gdt_start:
    dd 0
    dd 0

gdt_code:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0

gdt_end:

CODE EQU gdt_code - gdt_start
DATA EQU gdt_data - gdt_start


You reenabled interrupts without having set up interrupt handlers for at least the timer interrupt.

Single-step your code with a debugger. QEMU can act as a GDB remote.  The first problem I notice is that you're using a [gdt_descriptor] addressing mode without having set up DS=0 to match your ORG.  And that you set SP without first setting SS.   See Boot loader doesn't jump to kernel code for Michael Petch's general tips for bootloaders.

The flashing you see is because a triple fault causes the machine to reboot. Run QEMU with the options -d int -no-shutdown -no-reboot -monitor stdio . That should stop it from rebooting on a triple fault and also gives you an opportunity to look at the CPU state in the QEMU monitor. -d int will do a state dump on each interrupt/exception. As Jester pointed out it is probably because you enable interrupts in protected mode without and idt and handlers. I would expect with the QEMU options I gave there was probably a v=08 dump when the first timer came in.

I'd actually recommend BOCHS to do low level GDT/IDT real mode/protected mode switch debugging. QEMU doesn't have very good debugging support for real mode 20-bit segment:offset addressing.
